# Magento 2.3.2 - Product customisable options reappear by themselves

Tags: magento2, product, customizable-options

I've been experiencing a weird issue in my project where every now and then (once a month-two months), some of our products  (that once had customizable options, yet they were eventually removed) have all the customizable options back, despite no one going and consciously re-adding those options again.

Here are the options for example:
[image: custom options]

Has anyone ever experienced something like this? What could trigger re-adding old data to products a few months after its removed? We have an extension that logs any changes to products and there's simply nothing regarding this. I'm at a loss.

Appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The options could be added through an api user. Or a recurring data event.